# How to check numpy array is empty?

Tags: python, numpy

How do I test if a numpy array is empty. I have problem if the there is only one element with value `0`. If I do

```
a = np.array([0])
a.any()
```

results is `False` while

```
a = np.array([1])
a.any()
```

is `True`
So how do I check `np.array` has no elements?

Comment: Check if a.size == 0 should do the trick

Comment: at the moment I do `len(a) == 1` to capture the only element with value 0. Better perhaps to use `a.size != 0`

Comment: Checking the `size` makes most sense.  But why why do you need to check this?  Is this a 1d array?  How is it created?

Comment: The future warning produced by `bool(np.array([]))` suggests using `array.size > 0`.

Comment: The array contains a list of index numbers where a value is duplicate in another list. If the array is not empty then I remove these elements. This worked all fine until I came across one where the index value was zero.

Comment: `np.nonzero` (`np.where`) produces a tuple of indexing arrays. Those may be size 0 if nothing in the condition is True,